# scroll event for single select drop down in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have single select drop down . At initial load, will get 100 options populated in the drop down. On scroll down to 100th option , I need to make service call to get next 100 option and has to append to first 100 options .

My issue here is I am not able to bind scroll event for single select drop down.

                                            Select One
                                            {{approver.firstname+','+approver.lastname}}

At the same time this scroll event is triggering for Multiple select drop down.

```
                                    <option *ngFor="let unassigned of unassignedList" value="{{unassigned.org_id}}">{{unassigned.name}}</option>
                                </select>
```

Please help on single select scroll event to be triggered on scrolling to nth item(last item) in drop down.